# Proof by Induction, Prove a Function is Identically Zero by Bounding it by a Sequence Converging to Zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, induction

I study the paper "Arbitrage an Martingales" by Morton and the autor presents a technical lemma (Lemma 4.6.3), in which I am very confident he mixed up notation. I tried to prove it myself but I am stuck in the induction step. Here is my work so far:

**Lemma:**
Suppose $H:\{(s,t)\mid 0\leq s\leq t\leq T\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is bounded and satisfies $$H(s,t)\leq L\int_{0}^{s}\left(\int_{u}^{t}H(u,y)dy+H(u,t)\right) du$$
for all $(s,t)$ in the domain of $H$. Then $H\equiv 0$.

**Proof:**
Since $H$ is bounded, there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $H(s,t)\leq M$ for all $(s,t)$. We show by induction that for every integer $k$ \begin{align*}
   H(s,t)\leq (T+1)^kL^kM\frac{t^k}{k!}.
  \end{align*}

- For $k=0$, we get $H(s,t)\leq M$, which is true by assumption.
- Suppose the claim holds for $k=n$. This is our induction hypothesis $[I]$. We are going to show that this implies that it holds for $k=n+1$ as well. Indeed,
  \begin{align*}
      H(s,t)&\stackrel{[I]}\leq L\int_{0}^{s}\left(\int_{u}^{t}(T+1)^kL^kM\frac{y^k}{k!}dy+(T+1)^kL^kM\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)du\\
      &= (T+1)^kL^{k+1}M\frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{s}\left(\int_{u}^{t}y^kdy+t^k\right)du\\
      &=(T+1)^kL^{k+1}M\frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{s}\left(\frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{u^{k+1}}{k+1}+t^k\right)du\\
      &=(T+1)^kL^{k+1}M\frac{1}{k!}s\left(\frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}-\frac{s^{k+1}}{(k+1)(k+2)}+t^k\right)
     \end{align*}

From here one might bound the expression by replacing the $s$ in front of the brackets by $T+1$, however this does not solve the induction step.

**My question** is therefore whether I am on the wrong path cconcerning the proof or wheter the lemma (the way I belive the author meant to write it down) is wrong or if there is another proof for this. Amy help is much appreciated.